# does linq-to-sql entity serialization work out of the box?

Tags: linq-to-sql, serialization

If I try to serialize a linq-to-sql entity, will it by default serialize only the primitive fields or will it try to access the relationship fields as well? If it tries to grab relationship fields, is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which serializer are you using?

- The DataContractSerializer will
  include loaded relationships but not
  those that are not yet loaded / null.
- The XmlSerializer tend to choke on relationships if they are bidirectional (i.e. entity A points to entity B which in turn points back).
- The binaryformatter ... I never got that one to work properly with L2S entity objects having relationships to other entities. Long time since I tried though, so maybe I just did something wrong...

Comment: I haven't decided on a serializer yet, I was hoping that one of them had the option or by default didn't try at all to traverse the relationship properties. I was going to try System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer first.

Comment: Ok. The DataContractSerializer is your best bet with L2S generated entity classes. If you want to exclude any already loaded relations, you need to null them out or fiddle with the datamember properties on the association properties...

Answer (score 0):

Another point to add to the accepted answer:

Relationships that are not collections will **never be serialized** by DataContractSerializer (whether they are loaded or not), because no `DataMember` attribute is generated for them from the `.dbml` file.

[I found here](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/14/entity-refs-not-getting-serialized-with-wcf-service.aspx#6399262) an explanation by then-at-Microsoft Daniel Simmons:

> The issue here is that prior to SP1 there was really no good way with DataContract serialization to handle graphs of objects that had cycles.  As a result for LINQ to SQL the compromise decision was made to allow users to opt-in for uni-directional serialization and to only serialize collections not references.  This mechanism doesn't work well for cases where you really want to serialize a reference (like your scenario above), but it at least gets you going for some common scenarios.
>
> In SP1 new support was added to WCF which enables DataContract serialization to deal with cycles, but it is something you must opt-in to by changing some of your DataContract attributes and potentially also making changes to your collection and reference class implementations to properly handle the serializaiton and especially the deserialization behaviors of WCF.  In the Entity Framework the changes were made to take advantage of these new features since it had not yet released its very first version, but Linq to SQL only had a small service-pack upgrade in sp1 and it was not modified to take advantage of this capability.
>
> I have not experimented with this on L2S, but it might be possible to generate your own classes which work with L2S and have the right support for WCF serialization with cycles.
>
> Danny